# selecting slider to display in r shinyapps

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use selectInput in shiny aps to create a menu that changes the displayed slider.

```
ui <- fluidPage (
    selectInput (inputId = "sat_act", "Choose your test:", 
            c("SAT" = "SATscore", "ACT" = "ACTscore")
    sliderInput (inputId = "SATscore",
        label = "Select your SAT score", step = 10,
        value = 1000, min = 400, max = 1600),
    sliderInput (inputId = "ACTscore",
        label = "Select your ACT score", 
        value = 18, min = 1, max = 36)
    plotOutput (outputId = "graph")
        )

server <- function(input,output){}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Currently, my code displays boy sliders and has no drop down menu. I am uncertain how to implement this and have not found an example online. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: does one of the answers fulfills what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `renderUI()`.

On server side you evaluate your `sat_act` input and depending of the choice you render the new ui element:

```
output$score <- renderUI({
    if(input$sat_act == "SATscore"){
      return(...)
    }
  })
```

Full app:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage (
               selectInput (inputId = "sat_act", "Choose your test:", 
                c("SAT" = "SATscore", "ACT" = "ACTscore")),
               uiOutput("score"),
               plotOutput (outputId = "graph")
)

server <- function(input,output){
  output$score <- renderUI({
    if(input$sat_act == "SATscore"){
      return(
        sliderInput (inputId = "SATscore",
                     label = "Select your SAT score", step = 10,
                     value = 1000, min = 400, max = 1600)
      )
    }else{
      return(
        sliderInput (inputId = "ACTscore",
                     label = "Select your ACT score", 
                     value = 18, min = 1, max = 36)    
      )
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an UI

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage (
  selectInput(inputId = "sat_act", "Choose your test:", 
              c("SAT" = "SATscore", "ACT" = "ACTscore")),
  uiOutput('slider'),
  plotOutput (outputId = "graph")
)

server <- function(input,output){
  output$slider = renderUI({
    if (input$sat_act == 'SATscore') {
      sliderInput(inputId = "SATscore",
              label = "Select your SAT score", step = 10,
              value = 1000, min = 400, max = 1600)
    } else {
      sliderInput(inputId = "ACTscore",
              label = "Select your ACT score", 
              value = 18, min = 1, max = 36)
    }

  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```